# Pyspark regexp_replace

Tags: pyspark, regexp-replace

I am trying to replace values in a dataframe based on a when condition.

i.e. Data frame values:

```
country_code|country_code_iso3

|       UA-09|             null|

|       UA-14|             null|

|       UA-43|               UA|
```

I run this code:

```
df.withColumn('country_code_iso3', 
    when(df.country_code.startswith('UA-'),regexp_replace('country_code_iso3','','UKR'))
    .when(df.country_code.startswith('UA-'),regexp_replace('country_code_iso3','UA','UKR'))                                               
   .otherwise(df.country_code_iso3))
```

but my results end up like this:

```
|country_code|country_code_iso3|

|       UA-09|             null|

|       UA-14|             null|

|       UA-43|      UKRUUKRAUKR|
```

I want to look like this:

```
|country_code|country_code_iso3|

|       UA-09|              UKR|

|       UA-14|              UKR|

|       UA-43|              UKR|
```

Any idea how I can tweak my code to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to UKR whenever it starts with UA-, you can just do this...also in your code your first `when` statement is causing the issue and your other `when` is never hit because the condition has already been meet

```
df = (df
    .withColumn('country_code_iso3', 
        when((df.country_code.startswith('UA-')),lit('UKR'))   
        .otherwise(df.country_code_iso3))
)

df.show()

+------------+-----------------+
|country_code|country_code_iso3|
+------------+-----------------+
|       UA-09|              UKR|
|       UA-14|              UKR|
|       UA-43|              UKR|
+------------+-----------------+
```